# write a reverse proxy in node js to call the api in django

Tags: python, angularjs, node.js, django, reverse-proxy

My frontend code is running in angular at node httpserver port 127.0.0.1:8081
My backend services runnning in python django framework at port 127.0.0.1:9000
While calling my backend servies from angular http methods throws cors exception
so i wrote a proxy controller in my node js

```
var http = require('http'),
httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    // This simulates an operation that takes 500ms to execute
    setTimeout(function () {
        proxy.web(req, res, {
            target: 'http://127.0.0.1:9000/dummy/'
        });
    }, 500);
}).listen(8080, "127.0.0.1");
```

to listen and bind at angular. i run as the node proxycontroller.js, results a another port no 127.0.0.1:8080

from proxy controller it calls my backend service and result json but from the angular js calling the proxy controller from the http.get() method results cors problem

please help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable `CORS` in Django

Uses this third-party lib [django-cors](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/) to do it.

You are getting CORS because you are making the call from your AngularJS app and its host is `127.0.0.1:8081`, different from your Django app host `127.0.0.1:9000`

Comment: I have added the django-cors but still reporting the cors at front end

Comment: `$http({
   method: 'GET',
   url: '127.0.0.1:9000/dummy/'
 }).then(function successCallback(response) {
     // this callback will be called asynchronously
     // when the response is available
     $scope.success = response.data;
     console.log(success.server);
   }, function errorCallback(response) {
     // called asynchronously if an error occurs
     // or server returns response with an error status.
     console.log('error in the get call');
   });`

Comment: @user288093 what do you have in your ALLOWED_HOST in your settings.py

Comment: `INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'corsheaders',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []`

Comment: allowed host is empty array

Comment: @user288093 just for testing, use this `ALLOWED_HOST = ["*"]`

Comment: Actually from proxy server port its accepting the backend service but the front end angular calling the proxy server tells the cors issue
I think there is a problem in front end

Comment: `$http({
   method: 'GET',
   url: '127.0.0.1:8080'
 }).then(function successCallback(response) {
     // this callback will be called asynchronously
     // when the response is available
     $scope.success = response.data;
     console.log(success.server);
   }, function errorCallback(response) {
     // called asynchronously if an error occurs
     // or server returns response with an error status.
     console.log('error in the get call');
   });`

it calls the proxy server and proxy call the backend service as 127.0.0.1:9000.
front end port running at 127.0.0.1:8081

Comment: There is no problem with django api as we config the django-cors at backend in settings.py.
Need to call the request with http header.
as http://127.0.0.1:9000 accepts the django backend api service. No need to create the proxy server as well.

Answer (score 0):

The error said CORS is supported only for specific protocals like http:// etc. So you have to add http to that url. When you say, 127.0.0.1, the browser is unable to understand which protocol to use to access that url, should it be using http:// or data:// or chrome:// etc. So you've to explicitly say http://

You have to configure cors in the backend. The backend (the API server) much explcitly say a site is allowed using the http header I specified earlier. Otherwise, I can open your website, edit the frontend using chrome console and remove all the security stuff. It has the be in the backend.

as http://127.0.0.1:9000 from the front end angular app, dosent need to create proxy server to transfer the calls to backend service.